# The PGconn, PGresult, and PGError constants are deprecated on Heroku and Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I reset the database on Heroku in the database setting and ran `heroku run rake db:migrate`. Although it created all the data tables with correct columns per local database, it does not migrate any existing local data. Heroku database is just empty. In the past I ran the above code and worked fine but this time got stuck as shown below:

```
mac-a:skiny ran$ heroku run bundle exec rake db:migrate
Running bundle exec rake db:migrate on ⬢ blooming-citadel-66205... up, run.3076 (Hobby)
The PGconn, PGresult, and PGError constants are deprecated, and will be
removed as of version 1.0.

You should use PG::Connection, PG::Result, and PG::Error instead, respectively.

Called from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
```

As a note, I quit mac terminal while running `heroku run rake db:reset` and maybe there is some internal error...

Comment: Can you try this ? heroku run rake db:setup

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to the following, edit your Gemfile like below

```
gem 'pg', '~> 0.20.0'
```

Or

```
gem 'pg', '~> 0.11'
```

Then bundle install and try, it's working on my hand.

***Note:*** the tilde sign before the >, that's not a dash

Once you make this update in your group production of your Gemfile, ensure you run `bundle install --without production` (to update Gemfile.lock file), do a git add/commit cycle, then re-deploy to Heroku.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Migrations are not supposed to create data. They define tables, indexes, constraints, etc.

You should use db:seed, after migrating, to create data (besides adding pg  version as mentioned on other answer.)